# How to output xml namespace with Grails REST webservices

Tags: xml, rest, grails, namespaces

Its a Grails app and we'd like to be able to add XML namespaces to the xml produced for REST clients. Most of the xml is output using "render foo as XML" with the deep converter.

So the output needs to be something like:
`<foo xmlns:myns='http://mycompany.com/myproduct/ver'> ... </foo>`

Answer (score 1):

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Creating+XML+using+Groovy%27s+MarkupBuilder

```
def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
xml.'rec:records'('xmlns:rec': 'http://groovy.codehaus.org') {
  car(name:'HSV Maloo', make:'Holden', year:2006) {
    country('Australia')
    record(type:'speed', ' Truck with speed of 271kph')
  }
}

result

<rec:records xmlns:rec='http://groovy.codehaus.org'>
  <car name='HSV Maloo' make='Holden' year='2006'>
    <country>Australia</country>
    <record type='speed'> Truck with speed of 271kph</record>
  </car>
</rec:records>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Aaron. We are using the "render foo as XML" construct, so how do we use the MarkupBuilder in this context? It's too much work to go to a manual serialization process in our case.

Comment: grails does not support it through the standard converters, see bug http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-5152